# Constructing $f(x)$ continuous at $x=a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

I would like to construct a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $f$ is continuous only at one point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and nowhere else. I have seen various threads, but cannot seem to find a general answer for any $a$. All the answers point to the classical example 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\\ x & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
which has the property that it is continuous at $0$ and nowhere else. In another post about this problem, someone stated "a similar line of reasoning can be used to construct a function that is continuous only at one specific point."

**Here is my attempt:** Let 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
a & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\\ x & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
We claim that $f(x)$ is continuous only at $x=a$. 
Let $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $c\neq a$, and set $\epsilon=\frac{|c-a|}{2}$. Then, for any $\delta>0$, there exists a number $x_0$ such that $|x_0-c|<\delta$ and $x_0\notin\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $|f(x_0)-f(c)|=|a-c|\nless\epsilon$. However, this function does not work for $c$ irrational...

Comment: Just translate the original function.  For $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ define $F_{\alpha}$ to be $f(x-\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes! As lulu said, the function should be analogously defined as $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}0 & x\notin \mathbb Q\\ x-a & x \in \mathbb Q\end{array}\right.$